# How to color in grid cell different values

Tags: asp.net

I need to distinguish ten consecutive cells.

Each one in a row, if they have different values, when databindind the values to a gridview.

so,this cells have different value. if this cells value is  <=3 then color is red and cells value >3 color is green.

I need  to color each cell using for loop condition.please any person tells me this solutions.What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try in `RowDataBound`

```
protected void YourGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

int _value = Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["<column_name>"].ToString());
if (_value <= 3)
{
  e.Rows.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
 else if (_value > 3)
 {
  e.Rows.ForeColor = Color.Green;
 }
}
```